# symfony2 - the assetic assetic:dump command doesn't create stylesheets correctly

Tags: php, css, symfony, assets, assetic

For some reason I can't load the css files.
Here is the structure of the bundle that I use

```
BD
 WebsiteBundle
   public
     css
```

And here is how I try to load the css files

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/bdwebsite/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I did `assetic:dump`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: so what's the URL look like in the html the browser receives? Is it the proper url for what you'd have to enter to manually hit the css file?

Comment: There is no url for the css files in the html file.

Comment: so the browser is receiving `href=""`?

Comment: No. There is no <link rel="stylesheet"... tag

Comment: javascript "import" works fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You referred to `bundles/bdwebsite/css/*` in your `stylesheets` tag.

This way assetic looks for all css files in `web/bundles/bdwebsite/css` (a folder that currently does not exist) and not in `src/BD/WebsiteBundle/public/css`.

In order to have your files in the right place **before** executing `assetic:dump`...

... use `app/console assets:install web` which will copy them to the web folder...

... or my recommendation `app/console assets:install web --symlink` for symlinks.